# How to decorate pyqt5 class using dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-dataclasses

I try to use python3 dataclass to decorate pyqt5 class, but in my method seems that it don't work?

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass()
class Demo(QWidget):
    name: str = 'jim'
    addr: str = 'usa'

app = QApplication([])
win = Demo()
win.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>In your code you indicate that `Qt` has a member called `Widget` that is clearly false, I recommend you analyze what you provide since it can be qualified as a typo.</sub>

But even correcting that error would not work since if you implement the dataclass on a class that inherits from another class you must implement the [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) method where you must call the [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) method:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


@dataclass
class Demo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    name: str = "jim"
    addr: str = "usa"

    def __post_init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Demo()
    print(win.name, win.addr)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I use pycharm and only want to import `Qt` namespace, probably when i input `Qt` word it auto complete and i don't see it clearly. Using  dataclass to write qt code seems not a good idea.